# How to obtain JSON from server on client side using node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've been at this for severals hours, and have to ask another set of keen eye's. Thanks in advance.

Basically, when I go to my URL(ex. 55.55.55.55/select), it sends JSON data for view from the database.

Now on the client side, I try to access the data but cannot for some reason. ****BTW, I do click to trigger the eventListener.
I've tried many different things, such as changing the code and researching but still cannot figure this out.

```
 document.getElementById('clicks').addEventListener('click', function(event){
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

var reqString = url + "/select";

req.open('GET', reqString, true);


req.addEventListener('load',function() {
if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {

    var response = req.responseText; // used to be var response = 

    // JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    document.getElementById('status').textContent = req.responseText;

    //console.log(response);
    //alert(response.name[0]);
    selectOption(response);
    //document.getElementById('status')..responsetext = req.responseText;

}else {
        // If a server error was received, post the response text to the   log
        console.log("Error in network request: " + req.statusText);
   }
   });

   req.send();

 //event.preventDefault();
 }); 


//html
<form id="clicks">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Data</legend>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="buttons" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
   </form>

<p id="status"></p>
<div>
    <select id="selectNumber">
        <option>Choose a Hotel</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script src="/script.js">

</script>
```

Edit:
(Not the issue): hotelScript.js:43 XMLHttpRequest cannot load %55.55.55.55/select. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: "cannot for some reason" is rather vague. What happens? What gets reported on the console? Does the load event handler fire? Do you see the request in the network tab of your browser's developer tools? What about the response?

Comment: I don't get any output from the console log. Let me try double checking on dev tools.

Comment: How does your URL looks. Is it `http://something` or `file:///somepath` ?? I mean your HTML page URL.

Comment: Its actually   `http://something`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can parseresult as json using:
var obj = JSON.parse( queryObj.jsonData );

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. The two just seem to not interact.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Same Domain origin policy (limitation). URL address of your server should match exactly PORT, HOST and protocol of the browser's url.

If node.js runs on different port (or even host) than your web application, you must create a reverese proxy on webserver.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does your **url** variable look like ?
It seems to miss the **http://** prefix.
Make sure it is in the url ...

Comment: and how are you running your client HTML code in the browser ? on a localhost web server or as a file ? what's written in your browser url bar ? http:// or file:/// ?

Answer (score 0):

```
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
req.end(JSON.stringify(payload));
```

these are required after the load

Answer (score -1):

First try in the navigator to access the URL and see if you get de JSON.

Anyway, I think you have to change `send` for `end`

```
res.end(tableInfo);
```

the `end` function closes the connection. Then the navigator knows the transmition was ended and all the data is transfered

Also change

```
req.addEventListener('load',function() {
```

by

```
req.addEventListener('onreadystatechange',function() {
```

Comment: Yes, I get the JSON when I go directly to 55.55.55.55/select but not from the other page.

Comment: Do you try change `send` by `end`? Try also changing `document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = req.responseText;` with `document.getElementById('status').textContent = req.responseText;`

Comment: Still the same, this might be an EventListener problem though I can't see why, No eventListeners show up on the dev tools.